# Javascript delay a loop till iframe is loaded in first iteration

Tags: javascript, loops, async-await

I have a javascript loop that executes a couple of functions. The first function loads an iframe and the second function clicks an element on that iframe. I want the loop not to run the second function until the iframe is finished loading. But I am not sure how to achieve this.
So far I have done this but doesn't seem to do the job

Loop :

```
action.steps.forEach(step => {
       window[step.functionName](step.functionParameter); 
});
```

First function

```
function goToUrl(url) {
    let iframeDocument = document.querySelector('iframe');
    iframeDocument.src = url;
    let iframeLoaded;

    iframeDocument.onload = () => {
        iframeLoaded = true
    }

    async function checkLoad() {
        if (iframeLoaded) {
            alert("page loaded");
            return true;
        } else {
            await sleep(500);
            checkLoad();
            
        }
    }
    checkLoad();
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}
```

second function

```
function clickOnElement(elementSelector) {
    var element = iframeDocument.querySelector(elementSelector);
    element.click();
}
```

Comment: `checkload` is an async function, but you are not awaiting it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first function is an asynchronous operation, which can be modified to return a Promise that resolves when the frame is loaded. This also means you don't need to recursively `checkLoad`.

```js
function goToUrl(url) {
    const iframeDocument = document.querySelector('iframe');
    iframeDocument.src = url;

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        // calls `resolve()` when loaded
        iframeDocument.onload = resolve;
    });
}
```

The second function needs to wait for the first function to be resolved.
To generalise this pattern, you can modify your loop as an asynchronous function,
which `await`s for the result of a step if that step's function returns a Promise (e.g. your `goToUrl` function:

```
async function yourLoop() {
  // each step could be synchronous or asynchronous
  for (const step of actions.step) {
    const result = window[step.functionName](step.functionParameter);
    if (result instanceof Promise) {
        // if step is asynchronous operation, wait for it to complete
        await result;
    }
  }
}

/////// usage ////////

yourLoop().then(() => {
  /* all steps completed */
}).catch(() => {
  /* some step(s) failed */
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Whenever a timer or event handler is needed, I usually prefer not to do a traditional loop nor mess with promises/awaits.

Instead what I would do is something similar to this. Basically waiting in onload to run the callback function then moving on to the next function in the loop.

```
let max = action.steps.length;
let cur = 0;

function loadIframe(url) {
  let iframeDocument = document.querySelector('iframe');
  iframeDocument.src = url;
  let iframeLoaded;

  iframeDocument.onload = () => {
     let step = action.steps[cur];
     window[step.functionName](step.functionParameter); 
     if(cur < max){
         cur++;
         loadIframe(step.url)
     }
  }
}

loadIframe(action.steps[cur].url);
```